# How to remove "-" and a space from the beginning in a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have an output that looks as below

```
- 0.1-1
- 0.1-2
- 0.1-3
- 0.1-6
- 0.1-7
- 0.1-9
```

How to use grep or something else so as to remove  "-"  and a space from the beginning.

```
0.1-1
0.1-2
0.1-3
0.1-6
0.1-7
0.1-9
```

Comment: grep just finds stuff. it doesn't "change" it. you need other tools.

Comment: Surely this is a duplicate...

Answer (score 2):

With sed:

```
sed -e 's/^- //' input.txt
```

Or with GNU grep:

```
grep -oP '^- \K.*' input.txt
```

Comment: `-P` is available on fewer builds of GNU grep than `-o` is (introduced in a later release, and requires an extra compile-time option that modifies the set of library dependencies and thus isn't likely to be available on embedded systems).

Answer (score 1):

You may use grep also,

```
grep -oE '[0-9].*' file
```

Comment: That still prints the whole line, not only the subpart matched; you'd need GNU extensions for that.

Comment: added -o flag....

Comment: *nod*. Worth noting, though, that that isn't in [the POSIX standard for `grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/grep.html), so its presence on any particular platform isn't guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
awk '{print $2}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cut to remove the first two columns of every line:

```
cut -c3- input.txt
```

Comment: You probably meant  `-c3-`.